# Select multiple rows that correspond to a single condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where **POST_ID** contains an `ID` (that identifies a post), **META_KEY** contains the type of data (“*latitude*” or “*longitude*”) and **META_VALUE** contains the value for the key.

```
POST_ID META_KEY  META_VALUE
   1879 latitude   14.846329
   1879 longitude  42.947395
   1849 latitude   18.543265
   1849 longitude  41.849382
   1754 latitude   14.846329
   1754 longitude  41.849382
```

In simple English, I need to know the `ID` of the post where *latitude* is *14.846329* and *longitude* is *42.947395* (in this case *1879*)

I am totally confused at the moment: **what’s the `MySQL` query to get the correct result?**

Thanks.

Comment: what queries have you tried?

Comment: please specify whether is it top 1 or any min post_ID?

Comment: So you need the maximum value of both latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 2):

Group by the `post_id` and take only those having these values

```
select post_id
from your_table
group by post_id
having sum(meta_key = 'latitude' and meta_value = '14.846329') > 0
   and sum(meta_key = 'longitude' and meta_value = '42.947395') > 0
```

Comment: Good answer. Would have been better with the explanation that `true` = 1 and `false` = 0 in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses a `join`:

```
select t.post_id
from t tlat join
     t tlong
     on tlat.post_id = tlong.post_id and
        tlat.meta_key = 'latitude' and tlat.meta_value = '14.846329'
        tlong.meta_key = 'longitude' and long.meta_value = '42.947395';
```

Note:  This uses single quotes, assuming that the `meta_value` is a string.